# Permitir caracteres especiales en expresión regular JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Tegno el siguiete código JavaScript

```js
function strong(){
        var element = document.getElementById("deco");
        var value = element.textContent || "";
        var regex = /\*([a-zA-Z\d\w\s]+)\*/gi; // STRONG

        value = value.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>"); // STRONG
      
       element.innerHTML = value; 
    } strong();
```

```html
<p id="deco">
*Lorem Ipsum* is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. *¿Lorem Ipsum, has beén?* the industry's standard dummy text ever since the *¡1500s!*
</p>
```

Las oraciones que están encerradas en asteriscos se convierten en strong, el problema, como lo pueden notar es que no funciona si tiene (**comas, tíldes, simbolos de expresión, etc...**) He probado agregandole estos caracteres a la expresión regular, pero no funciona.

Agradezco sus comentarios y respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependiendo de las reglas que quieras poner, usar una expresión regular para lo que quieres hacer puede volverse muy complicado: ¿Quieres aceptar asteriscos "escapados" para ponerlos en negrita? : `*en negrita \* con asterisco*` -> **en negrita * con asterisco**.

Si quieres una versión sencilla, puedes usar una expresión regular que capture todo lo que **no** sea un asterisco:

```js
function strong(){
        var element = document.getElementById("deco");
        var value = element.textContent || "";
        var regex = /\*([^\*]+)\*/gi; // STRONG

        value = value.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>"); // STRONG
      
       element.innerHTML = value; 
    } strong();
```

```html
<p id="deco">
*Lorem Ipsum* is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. *¿Lorem Ipsum, has beén?* the industry's standard dummy text ever since the *¡1500s!*
</p>
```